# std::vector resize() works only after clear()

Tags: c++, vector, resize

I have a vector object:

```
std::vector<std::vector<MyClass>> _matrix;
```

It is 2d array with some data.
When i trying to resize the dimensions with:

```
_matrix.resize(_rows, std::vector<MyReal>(_colms)); //_rows and _colms are ints
```

this command simply does nothing to the object.
So to resize it i have to call first to:

```
_matrix.clear();
```

and then:

```
_matrix.resize(_rows, std::vector<MyReal>(_colms));
```

Of course, I'm losing the data. (In my case it doesn't matter)

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Actualy only the colmumns size of _matrix doesn't change by the resize command.

Comment: I was wrong in my original question. Actualy only the colmumns size of _matrix doesn't change by the resize command.

Comment: As I side note, I think that variables starting with underscore are reserved for the compiler, and its probably better if you don't use them. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I use the underscore for a class private members. I think this is conventional.

Comment: @Tomas They're reserved if they start with a double underscore or an underscore and a capital letter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs for [`vector::resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wezs0zy6%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> _Val: The value of new elements added to the vector if the new size is larger that the original size.

Only the new rows get vectors with additional columns (`std::vector<MyReal>(_colms)`). `resize` will not change the existing rows.

**Update:** To resize the entire vector properly, iterate over the existing rows and resize those vectors, then add the new rows. Something like this should work:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < _matrix.size(); i++)
  _matrix[i].resize(_colms);
_matrix.resize(_rows, std::vector<MyReal>(_colms));
```

Comment: You are right. Is there is a way to resize to new rectangular size?

Comment: OK, I understand now the functionality of resize. In my case, when I don't mind losing the data, using clear() is more simple. Thanks.